# Adding click handler for nested elements in a div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add the same click event to two nested elements inside a `div`. The HTML structure is like this:

```
<li class="car>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Car of the Day</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="car-wrap">
        Content...
    </div>
    <div class="other-content">
        Contains other links and content
    </div>
</li>
```

The `<h2>` in the header and the `div.car-wrap` content are the clickable elements. I cant put the click event on the `li.car` as there are other link elements on the `div.other-content`. Also the structure of the HTML may vary depending on the type of result/car. For example in some the `div.header` may not be present.

So far I have this:

```
$('#results').on('click', 'li.car:not(".unpinned").car-wrap', function (e) { ...
```

Which works when I click on the `div.car-wrap`. But I don't want to replicate it just for the `<h2>`. Also I am trying to avoid adding another class to the markup if possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate selectors in a single jQuery object with a comma:

```
$('#results').on('click', 'li.car:not(".unpinned") .car-wrap, li.car:not(".unpinned") .header h2', function (e) { 
   // your code...
});
```

Also note the space between the `:not()` and the `.car-wrap` selector, as it's a descendant.

Comment: Yeah, I think the same when  I read the `li.car:not(.unpinned).car-wrap` without whitespace between

Comment: Thanks. Did not know you can add them like that